Trying to install VM but this pops up " Unable to locate package virtnst"
So when I type in the command  sudo apt install qemu-system-x86m libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virtnst libvirt-daemon virt-manager this pops up Unable to locate package virtnst and I am unsure why i've tried many things
sudo apt-get install virt-manager
 sudo apt update has been done
and I just can't find out what the issue is.

What "many things" have you tried?

You are trying unsuccessfully to install virtinst, but you mistakenly typed virtnst instead of virtinst. virtinst package contains utilities to create and edit virtual machines. It is a dependency of the virt-manager package which you are also trying to install. If you have virt-manager installed then you also have virtinst automatically installed along with it, even if you didn't try to install it specifically.
To install virtinst in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu run the following command (which is unnecessary in your case because virt-manager is already installed):
sudo apt install virtinst

